# Are bunnies supposed to spawn only on the surface?

Tags: terraria

Deep underground in Terraria, whilst fighting skeletons and killer bats, I came across the most fearsome creatures yet imaginable.

[image]

Aquatic Cave Bunnies!  AAAH!!

Aren't these guys only supposed to spawn on the surface?

Do bunnies actually spawn in caves?  Consistently?

Comment: The question may be amusing, but it's not really helpful. Also, as the only answer says, you can find anything on the page that has everything, including the facts on bunnies. :T

Comment: I shall leave it up, despite the probability of getting many downvotes, because it really did surprise me when I saw it.  And, maybe it'll remind people (like me) to check the Wiki first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first paragraph of the [Terraria Wikia page about Bunnies](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Bunny) clearly states:

> Bunnies are common, harmless creatures that spawn during the day. They do not inflict damage on players. They are found anywhere on the surface of the map and sometimes Underground.

So calm down, nothing out of the ordinary is happening.

Comment: Okay.  I clearly did panic a little about the cave bunnies.  Thank you for the answer all the same.